# Create new rows and put a flag to differentiate between existing row

Tags: r, data-manipulation

I have a dataset like this:

```
df_have <- data.frame(id = rep("a",3), time = c(1,3,5), flag = c(0,1,1))
```

The data has one row per time per id but I  need to have the second row duplicated and put into the `data.frame` like this:

```
df_want <- data.frame(id = rep("a",4), time = c(1,3,3,5), flag = c(0,0,1,1))
```

The flag variables should become 0 with the new row added and all other information the same. Any help would be appreciated.

Edit:
The comments below are helpful but I would also need to do this in groups by id and some ids have more rows than other ids. After reading this and seeing the comments below I see the logic isn't clear. My original data does not have a count variable (what I call flag) but it needs it in the final output. What I would need is that every row besides for the first and last timepoint (within each id) to be duplicated and every time there is a duplicate make a counter to demonstrate when a row was created until the next new row is created.

```
df_have2 <- data.frame(id = c(rep("a",3),rep("b",4))  , 
                      time = c(1,3,5,1,3,5,7))


df_want2 <- data.frame(id = c(rep("a",4),rep("b",6)),
                       time = c(1,3,3,5,1,3,3,5,5,7),
                       flag = c(1,1,2,2,1,1,2,2,3,3))
```

Comment: Do you need `df_have[c(1, 2, 2, 3),]`?

Comment: perhaps `df_have %>% add_row(id = 'a', time = 3, flag = 0, .before = 2)` or `df_have %>% uncount(c(1, 2, 1)) %>% mutate(flag = replace(flag, 2, 0))`

Comment: @markusI might have been too simple with my example I created an update to reflect closer to the current scenario

Comment: @akrun thank you for that, how would uncount work with a group by and groups of varying lengths ?

Comment: Are you repeating for every row in `df_have2` regardless of the value of `flag`? Why are some flags `2` in `df_want2` and not `1` or `0`?

Comment: 1) How do you decide which rows to repeat? Why in `df_have2` row 2 of group a repeats and why row 2 and 3 of group b repeats? 2) How do you decide the value of `flag` ?

Comment: @Mike The `df_want2` values in `flag` logic is not clear.  Can you update the post with description

Comment: @akrun I tried to update the logic for the question to be clearer

Comment: @Mike Based on the description and the new data, I guess the solution I posted below should work.  Please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could expand the data with `slice` and then create the 'flag' by `match`ing the 'time' with `unique` values of 'time' and take the `lag` of it

```
library(dplyr)
df_have2 %>% 
     group_by(id) %>% 
     slice(rep(row_number(), c(1, rep(2, n() - 2), 1))) %>%
     mutate(flag = lag(match(time, unique(time)),  default = 1)) %>% 
     ungroup
# A tibble: 10 x 3
#   id     time  flag
#   <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 a         1     1
# 2 a         3     1
# 3 a         3     2
# 4 a         5     2
# 5 b         1     1
# 6 b         3     1
# 7 b         3     2
# 8 b         5     2
# 9 b         5     3
#10 b         7     3
```